# Is there a way I can Integrate my python code into react native expo

Tags: python, react-native, expo, mediapipe

**Following is my Python Code that I want to use as a backend functionality within my react native mobile app:**

In this code I have a bunch of functions that perform different computer vision functions when a certain corresponding value is entered such as 1,2 etc. I want to connect each function to a separate button in my react native code.

**My research:**

So far what I have figured is that there is no way I can use this file directly in react native and that I will have to rewrite the entire code according to javascript but I dont want to do that.

The second possible option is to using API such as flask or Django. (I don't know much about this.)

the third option could be to use external process execution of expo.

*Please bear with me I am still learning and not an expert yet. Thank you*

**I can provide more details as well if required.**

**Python Code:**

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
import math
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
########################Video Capture###################
mp_draw=mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose=mp.solutions.pose
count=0
#level=None
def calculate_angle(a, b, c):
    a = np.array(a)  # First
    b = np.array(b)  # Mid
    c = np.array(c)  # End

    radians = np.arctan2(c[1] - b[1], c[0] - b[0]) - np.arctan2(a[1] - b[1], a[0] - b[0])
    angle = np.abs(radians * 180.0 / np.pi)

    if angle > 180.0:
        angle = 360 - angle

    return angle
def bicepsCurls_Right(count):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    level = None
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_tracking_confidence=0.5, min_detection_confidence=0.5) as pose:
        while capture.isOpened():
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            # changeing image color
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False
            # Making detection
            res = pose.process(image)
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            ########################################
            # extract landmarks
            try:
                landmarks = res.pose_landmarks.landmark
                # Get coordinates
                shoulder_r = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                              landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow_R = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist_R = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].y]

                # Calculate angle

                angle = calculate_angle(shoulder_r, elbow_R, wrist_R)




                # Visualize angle
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                            tuple(np.multiply(elbow_R, [780, 240]).astype(int)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                            )

                # Curl counter logic
                if angle > 160:
                    level = "down"
                if angle < 45 and level == 'down':
                    level = "up"
                    count += 1
                    print(count)


            except:
                pass

            #  cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (300, 100), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, 'COUNT', (20, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(count),
                        (10, 80),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.putText(image, 'LEVEL', (100, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, level,
                        (95, 75),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            mp_draw.draw_landmarks(image, res.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            print(res)
            cv2.imshow('Right side Bicep Curls', image)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def bicepsCurls_left(count):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    level = None
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_tracking_confidence=0.5, min_detection_confidence=0.5) as pose:
        while capture.isOpened():
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            # changeing image color
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False
            # Making detection
            res = pose.process(image)
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            ########################################
            # extract landmarks
            try:
                landmarks = res.pose_landmarks.landmark
                # Get coordinates
                shoulderl = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                             landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow_l = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist_l = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y]
                shoulder_r = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                              landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow_R = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist_R = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].y]

                # Calculate angle

                angle = calculate_angle(shoulderl, elbow_l, wrist_l)




                # Visualize angle
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                            tuple(np.multiply(elbow_l, [780, 240]).astype(int)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                            )

                # Curl counter logic
                if angle > 160:
                    level = "down"
                if angle < 35 and level == 'down':
                    level = "up"
                    count += 1
                    print(count)


            except:
                pass

            #  cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (300, 100), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, 'COUNT', (20, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(count),
                        (10, 80),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.putText(image, 'LEVEL', (100, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, level,
                        (95, 75),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            mp_draw.draw_landmarks(image, res.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            print(res)
            cv2.imshow('Left Side Bicep_curls', image)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def Situps(count):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture('c.mp4')
    level = None
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_tracking_confidence=0.8, min_detection_confidence=0.9) as pose:
        while capture.isOpened():
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            # changeing image color
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False
            # Making detection
            res = pose.process(image)
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            ########################################
            # extract landmarks
            try:
                landmarks = res.pose_landmarks.landmark
                # Get coordinates
                shoulder = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                            landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                hip = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].x,
                       landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].y]
                knee = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_KNEE.value].x,
                        landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_KNEE.value].y]

                # Calculate angle
                angle = calculate_angle(shoulder, hip, knee)

                # Visualize angle
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                            tuple(np.multiply(hip, [780, 240]).astype(int)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                            )

                # Curl counter logic
                if angle > 100:
                    level = "down"
                if angle < 35 and level == 'down':
                    level = "up"
                    count += 1
                    print(count)

            except:
                pass

            #  cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (300, 100), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, 'COUNT', (20, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(count),
                        (10, 80),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.putText(image, 'LEVEL', (100, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, level,
                        (95, 75),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            mp_draw.draw_landmarks(image, res.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            print(res)
            cv2.imshow('Situps', image)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def Squats(count):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture('squats.mp4')
    level = None
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_tracking_confidence=0.5, min_detection_confidence=0.5) as pose:
        while capture.isOpened():
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            # changeing image color
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False
            # Making detection
            res = pose.process(image)
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            ########################################
            # extract landmarks
            try:
                landmarks = res.pose_landmarks.landmark
                # Get coordinates
                shoulder = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                            landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x,
                         landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,
                         landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y]

                # Calculate angle
                angle = calculate_angle(shoulder, elbow, wrist)

                # Visualize angle
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                            tuple(np.multiply(elbow, [780, 240]).astype(int)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                            )


                if angle > 160:
                    level = "up"
                if angle < 70 and level == 'up':
                    level = "down"
                    count += 1
                    print(count)

            except:
                pass

            #  cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (300, 100), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, 'COUNT', (20, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(count),
                        (10, 80),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.putText(image, 'LEVEL', (100, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, level,
                        (95, 75),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            mp_draw.draw_landmarks(image, res.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            print(res)
            cv2.imshow('Squats', image)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def Pushups(count):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture('pushup.mp4')
    level = None
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_tracking_confidence=0.8, min_detection_confidence=0.9) as pose:
        while capture.isOpened():
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            # changeing image color
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False
            # Making detection
            res = pose.process(image)
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            ########################################
            # extract landmarks
            try:
                landmarks = res.pose_landmarks.landmark
                # Get coordinates
                shoulder = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                            landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x,
                         landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,
                         landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y]

                # Calculate angle
                angle = calculate_angle(shoulder, elbow, wrist)

                # Visualize angle
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                            tuple(np.multiply(elbow, [780, 240]).astype(int)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                            )

                # Curl counter logic
                if angle > 160:
                    level = "up"
                if angle < 70 and level == 'up':
                    level = "down"
                    count += 1
                    print(count)

            except:
                pass

            #  cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (300, 100), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, 'COUNT', (20, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(count),
                        (10, 80),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.putText(image, 'LEVEL', (100, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, level,
                        (95, 75),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            mp_draw.draw_landmarks(image, res.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            print(res)
            cv2.imshow('PushUPS', image)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def Jumingjacks(count):
    level=None
    capture=cv2.VideoCapture('Jumping Jacks.mp4')
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_tracking_confidence=0.8, min_detection_confidence=0.9) as pose:
        while capture.isOpened():
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            # changeing image color
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False
            # Making detection
            res = pose.process(image)
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            ########################################
            # extract landmarks
            try:
                landmarks = res.pose_landmarks.landmark
                # Get coordinates
                shoulderl = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                             landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                hip_l = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].x,
                         landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].y]
                wrist_l = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y]
                shoulder_R = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x,
                              landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow_R = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist_R = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].x,
                           landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].y]

                # Calculate angle
                angle = calculate_angle(wrist_l, shoulderl, hip_l)

                # Visualize angle
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                            tuple(np.multiply(shoulderl, [780, 240]).astype(int)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                            )

                # Curl counter logic
                if angle > 165:
                    level = "down"
                if angle < 15 and level == 'down':
                    level = "up"
                    count += 1
                    print(count)

            except:
                pass

            #  cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (300, 100), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, 'COUNT', (20, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(count),
                        (10, 80),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.putText(image, 'LEVEL', (100, 15),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, level,
                        (95, 75),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            mp_draw.draw_landmarks(image, res.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            print(res)
            cv2.imshow('Juming Jacks', image)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def main():
    print("Welcome to the AR Trainer\n Select the Below Exersice to Start:\n1:Bicep Curls: \n2:Situps: \n3:Pushups: \n4:Squats: \n5:Jumping Jacks: ")
    choice=int(input("Enter Exersice Number"))
    if(choice==1):
        side=input("enter Side")
        if(side=="left"):
            bicepsCurls_left(count)
        else:
            bicepsCurls_Right(count)
    if(choice==2):
        Situps(count)
    if(choice==3):
        Pushups(count)
    if(choice==4):
        Squats(count)
    if(choice==5):
        Jumingjacks(count)
    else:
        print("sorry were not able to perform this Exersice Yet")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite to JS, I think the second option is the way to go.
You'll need to connect your Expo App to your Python API (I suggest FastAPI, https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) using a https library such as axios or native fetch.

Comment: thank you @ChristophRackwitz but I am just gonna go with the API solution It's simple and understandable. The reponse on the github are confusing and doesn't have much sopport for it.

Comment: Hey @RobertoYoc , I have created the API for my mediapipe model. But I am having trouble connecting it to my react native app. Especially with the part where video stream has to be passed to API in realtime. I would be grateful if you can help me solve this problem. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, Can you please confirm if this AAR methodology would work with react native? the documentation has'nt mentioned it anywhere. Also I have heard that mediapipe has been purchased by google and they have removed its support from react native? is this true?